# sudo apt-get update doesn't work after uninstalling python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, apt

I uninstalled python2.7 from my Ubuntu 16.04 system using command
`sudo apt-get remove python2.7` but after doing this `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install` returns error. While python 2.7 is still installed because doing `python2.7` opens up python2.7 interpreter. I think I deleted important python packages but I am not sure.

```
 Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-pymysql
 python-xdg
 deluge-common
 deluge-gtk
 gimp
 gnome-tweak-tool
 gyp
 inkscape
 python-simplegeneric
 ipython
 python-pycurl
 python-tornado
 python-zmq
 ipython-notebook
 python-antlr
 python-appindicator
 python-bs4
 python-cvxopt
 python-six
 python-html5lib
 python-imaging
 python-lxml
 python-pyparsing
 python-tz
 python-matplotlib
 python-nose
 python-openpyxl
 python-pandas
 python-pil.imagetk:amd64
 python-pip
 python-ptyprocess
 python-py
 python-pyasn1
 python-pyasn1-modules
 python-pygame
 python-pyglet
 python-pytest
 python-serial
 python-setuptools
 python-simplejson
 python-sklearn
 python-sympy
 python-tables
 python-urwid
 python-wheel
 python-xlrd
 python-xlwt
 python-statsmodels
 python-zope.interface
 trash-cli
 xia
 Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: NEVER, Delete  Python2.7 from ubuntu distributions. every major program or application uses python2.7 in ubuntu.

Comment: Does it work? I mean is the interpreter functional?

Comment: `sudo apt purge python2.x-minimal`
By doing so you shall be removing all the programs depending upon python 2.7, The problem is ubuntu based distros are very much dependent on python 2.7 so it is never a good idea to remove python 2.7.
Thanks, I hope it will be helpful for you.

Comment: I learnt my lesson the hard way and had to reinstall Ubuntu. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Once after you have uninstalled any package do a

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

which will remove all the packages that are associated with the one you have uninstalled. So that if you want it to be again installed it would not give any error and would reinstall everything.

Comment: Well this didn't solve the problem and I reinstalled Ubuntu. But thanks for your answer.